# Why do kfifo need smp_wmb even with spin_lock_irqsave in kernel in version 4.9.37

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, queue, barrier

there are two section codes in kernel lib/kfifo.c as below:

```
#define kfifo_in_spinlocked(fifo, buf, n, lock) \
({ \
    unsigned long __flags; \
    unsigned int __ret; \
    spin_lock_irqsave(lock, __flags); \
    __ret = kfifo_in(fifo, buf, n); \
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(lock, __flags); \
    __ret; \
})
```

```
static void kfifo_copy_in(struct __kfifo *fifo, const void *src,
    unsigned int len, unsigned int off) {
    unsigned int size = fifo->mask + 1;
    unsigned int esize = fifo->esize;
    unsigned int l;

    off &= fifo->mask;
    if (esize != 1) {
        off *= esize;
        size *= esize;
        len *= esize;
    }
    l = min(len, size - off);

    memcpy(fifo->data + off, src, l);
    memcpy(fifo->data, src + l, len - l);
    /*
     * make sure that the data in the fifo is up to date before
     * incrementing the fifo->in index counter
     */
    smp_wmb();
}
```

the function `kfifo_in` in `kfifo_in_spinlocked` will eventually call `kfifo_copy_in` function, my question is why even with `spin_lock_irqsave`, `smp_wmb` is needed? cpu got spin lock makes other cpu stall，so it can modified variables and data address exclusivly， when it unlock, others cpu can get the newest data and data address? why `smp_wmb` is needed?

Comment: Because `kfifo_in` is used without a spin-lock elsewhere in the kernel.

Comment: spin-lock is used, why smp_wmb is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, kfifo provides lock-free access in SPSC model (**Single** Producer **Single** Consumer). And the memory barrier is for concurrent accesses from a **reader** and from a **writer**.

In case of multiple producers (writers) it requires additional **synchronization between writers**, so only a single writer will be active at a time.

The function `kfifo_in_spinlocked` provides a way for such synchronization between writers: a spinlock.

Actually, locking aspects are described at the very top of [kfifo.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kfifo.h#L30) header:

```
/*
 * Note about locking: There is no locking required until only one reader
 * and one writer is using the fifo and no kfifo_reset() will be called.
 * kfifo_reset_out() can be safely used, until it will be only called
 * in the reader thread.
 * For multiple writer and one reader there is only a need to lock the writer.
 * And vice versa for only one writer and multiple reader there is only a need
 * to lock the reader.
 */
```